# SQL multiple AND statements

Tags: mysql, sql, statements

The problem is that I want to list the orders that haven´t been payed at the end of the selected month (for example october 31.10.2015)

That means:
list all orders from the beginning of time to 31.10
AND date_payed BETWEEN (1.11 - today)
AND date payed = NULL or before 1970

$sel_date = 10-2015  (the selected day)
$s3 = 11-2015 //in this case

```
from
  octt_order 
  WHERE order_status_id >= 1 
  AND (date_format(date_added,'%m-%Y') BETWEEN '11-2010' AND '$sel_date')
  AND (date_payed BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$s3','%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('11-2300','%m-%Y') OR date_payed is NULL)

  ORDER BY date_format(date_added,'%Y/%m/%d') ASC");
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution for me

```
octt_order 
  WHERE order_status_id >= 1 


  AND (date_added BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-2001','%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$s3','%m-%Y'))
  AND (date_payed BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$s3','%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('11-2300','%m-%Y') OR date_payed is NULL)     

  ORDER BY date_format(date_added,'%Y/%m/%d') ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `BETWEEN` doesn't compare dates but strings. So '02-2000' will come before '03-2000', but after '02-2020', which is probably not what you want. Compare dates (like in the second `BETWEEN`) to fix that.

The second `BETWEEN` looks like it could do with some more brackets, though you might get away with your version if the operator precedence works in your favour.

Your order by does not have to convert the date to a string. `ORDER BY date_added` would be fine.

It would help to know what you want, what you get, and what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I want to list the orders that haven´t been payed at the end of the selected month (for example october 31.10.2015)

That means:
list all orders from the beginning of time to 31.10
AND date_payed 1.11 - today
AND date payed = NULL or before 1970

Comment: I think you just want something (schematically) like this: `select * from table where date_added>'20151001' and date_added<'20151101' and (date_payed>'20151101' or date_payed is null)`. No need for all those `BETWEEN`s or weird date format conversions.

Answer (score 0):

You should do all date arithmetic and comparisons using the date data type, not strings.  If you have to use strings, then use ISO standard formats:  YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD.

So, you should switch the comparisons to using dates and use logic like this:

```
FROM octt_order 
WHERE order_status_id >= 1 AND
      date_added >= '2010-11-01' AND
      date_added < STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('$seldate', '-01'), '%m-%Y-%d') + interval 1 month AND
      date_payed >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('$s3', '-01'), '%m-%Y-%d') + interval 1 month AND
      (date_payed < '2300-12-01' or date_payed is null)
ORDER BY date_added asc
```

Comment: This results that no records are found. I edited my post here. Please check it